# Error 404: ProxyServlet: /activiti-explorer

Tags: xpages, activiti, bpmn

So, well, I am trying to get started with [Workflow for XPages](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Workflow%20for%20XPages/releases/D39FAF30D66B229D86257B6D001F11C0) however, I am not able to get the activiti-explorer working. I am trying to setup the application named "Sample Application on Activiti" (this application is present as one of the sample).

I followed the following steps as listed in the tutorial:

1. Installed Extension Library and H2 Database; and copied the active server plugins.
2. Installed the site.xml on client and server.
3. Started the h2 database.
4. Updated the activiti.workflow file

According to these steps when I visit "myServer/activiti-explorer" a login should come but instead I am getting the above mentioned error. The only solution I thought about was that the activiti-explorer.war file was to be kept in the domino directory somewhere (similar to webapps in tomcat: which works very well btw.). I tried putting it in "domino/data" directory with no success.

Also, there is an open topic on [openntf](http://openntf.org) discussion tab of the same project with no response yet. Just for reference the link is:

http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Workflow%20for%20XPages/discussions/6B020B585420E70886257B6E004E5A32

Edit 1: After digging in more, I found out that the domino throws a different error the very first time I try to access the activiti-explorer and rest all times it throws the same error mentioned in the title. However, the console looks something like this after the first request.

```
18-06-2014 12:17:17   HTTP JVM: Activiti Explore Started
18-06-2014 12:17:17   HTTP JVM: Web Container : com.ibm.pvc.internal.webcontainer.webapp.BundleDeployedModule : CWPWC0032E: Error occured while processing annotation for the servlet java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.activiti.explorer.servlet.ExplorerApplicationServlet.
18-06-2014 12:17:17   HTTP JVM: 1. The supported annotations are @DeclareRoles,@PreDestroy and @PostConstruct for servlets.
18-06-2014 12:17:17   HTTP JVM: 2. Check that the class resides in the proper package directory.
18-06-2014 12:17:17   HTTP JVM: 3. Check that the classname has been defined in the server using the proper case and fully qualified package.
18-06-2014 12:17:17   HTTP JVM: 4. Check that the class was transfered to the filesystem using a binary transfer mode.
18-06-2014 12:17:17   HTTP JVM: 5. Check that the class was compiled using the proper case (as defined in the class definition).
18-06-2014 12:17:17   HTTP JVM: 6. Check that the class file was not renamed after it was compiled. Thread[Thread-6,5,main]. For more detailed information, please consult error-log-0.xml located in C:/Program Files/IBM/Lotus/Domino/data/domino/workspace/logs
```

I understand it is a class not found exception but I am not sure how to get through it.

Any help would really be appreciated here. Thanks.

Comment: 404 means there is nothing at that URL. Double chceck what is supposed to be at the /activiti-explorer. Dig through configuration files. Another approach is to go through installation steps for second time.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I know what 404 means. As I mentioned in my question, I have tried putting it in the server directory but it doesn't work out. I have tried putting it in all possible server directories. I think there is something very small missing in the tutorial which I am not able to figure out. (Also refer the discussion on openntf it has the very same question)..

Comment: Domino afaik doesn't process war files anywhere. The equivalent is the structure of the nsf or the structure of a plug-in. Did you use the OSGi console to verify that the plug-ins have been loaded?

Comment: @ChintanParekh Think out of the box: you tried to copy files to any directory with no luck. That path points to a servlet (I am almost sure) that's why I said to look into configs.

Comment: @stwissel: yup the plugin was loaded successfully. However, the first time I try to open, I get a different set of errors(will just add it to the question)..@Frantisek: Can you please throw some more hint? Which configuration files? I went through the installation twice by following it through scratch on my other machine with no success. Also, please look a the error message I have appended to the question.

Comment: It's quite simple:
The class as specified in web.xml doesn't exist. It should be org.activiti.explorer.ExplorerApp.